# How to remove the commas from an array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a array of string
arry = [ "Laptop", "mobile", "car"]

i want to make this
arry = ["laptop" "mobile" "car"]

i tried it in ruby. but it doesn't matter any language as far as i can get the output in this format.

Comment: Your desired output is not valid Ruby code, therefore, you *cannot possibly* get this output.

Comment: I assume that your "array of string" is Ruby code. But what is the other one? Do you want to _print_ the array that way? Or are you looking for a more concise way to write your code? (theres `%w[laptop mobile car]`). Besides, it might help to understand _why_ you want to output it that way. Please clarify.

Comment: The first one does not have commas. The second one is not a syntactically valid denotation of an array.

Comment: @user1934428 I can clearly see 2 commas in `arry = [ "Laptop", "mobile", "car"]`

Comment: They are not **in** the array. If you print `arry[0]` or `arry[1]` or `arry[2]`, none of these elements will show you a comma. If no elements of the array have a comma, the whole array can't have one. Of yourse Ruby offers you an alternative way toe **write down** this array without **using** a comma: `arry1 = %w(Laptop mobile car)`, but this is the **same** array (i.e. `arry == arry1`.

Comment: @user1934428 take a look at the OP's code – it's not about the elements but the commas _between_ them. I'm not sure what this means, though.

Comment: @Stefan : That's exactly what I was refering to. Well, the question is closed now anyway, so perhaps the OP will reformulate his problem in a more understadable way ...

Answer (score 1):

There are no commas in any of your values, so no matter what you do you can't remove them. The commas are instead part of the language's default formatting when turning arrays into strings.

Instead of relying on that, turn the array into a string yourself:

```
arry = [ "Laptop", "mobile", "car"]
s = "[" + arry.map { |x| x.downcase.dump }.join(" ") + "]"
print s
```

This outputs `["laptop" "mobile" "car"]`